# Many-To-Many Association Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many, associations

I have the following models:

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
  has_many :categories, through: :restaurant_category
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :restaurants, through: :restaurant_category
end

class RestaurantCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :restaurant
  belongs_to :category
end
```

I would query in one shot all the categories associated to a restaurant. SOmething like this:

```
a = Restaurant.find(1)
a.restaurant_category
```

But I have:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `restaurant_category' for #<Restaurant:0x00007f5214ad2240>)
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
  has_many :categories, through: :restaurant_category
end
```

... should look like this:

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
  has_many :restaurant_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :restaurant_categories
end
```

Similarly, this:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :restaurants, through: :restaurant_category
end
```

... should look like this:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :restaurant_categories
  has_many :restaurants, through: :restaurant_categories
end
```

Which you would use like:

```
restaurant_categories = Restaurant.find(1).categories
```

This is all explained in the [has_many :through](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) section of the [Active Record Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) guide.